# Convert csv and first 0 value in column not displaying

Tags: json, angular, csv

working on a angular project converting an array on CSV format.

```
 var data = [
        {
        col1: "description",
        col2:"barcode",
        col3:"price",
        col4:"item number"
       },
       {
        col1: "description",
        col2:"090909",
        col3:"2",
        col4:"025909"
        }
  ]
```

this is my data format. I want to export this csv file. but for 090909 and 025909 first 0 is disappear. so how can i fixed this issue. I did check some post they suggested to add  = before value. how can add it.don't understand how to add = with value.i need to format is  ="090909" and ="025909".I am  using Angular2Csv module to convert JSON data in CSV in angular4 project

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm having trouble understanding what your problem statetment is ,could you elaborate?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv use the options object within the angular2csv package to escape whatever characters you want 
options = { 
   fieldSeparator: ',', 
    quoteStrings: ' " ', <-- use this to escape characters

Comment: `first 0 value` means? and can you please tell us where you added `=`

Comment: @ Javascript Lover - SKT
for example 090909  value have my data. but i goes to convert csv format and displaying 90909. first 0 is not displaying.

Comment: @SalmaKonaGugly please check this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-untvbm I think it is working fine

Comment: @Javascript Lover - SKT 
there is not displaying anything.

Comment: Have you tried to open CSV in text editor? Probably it would be there but Open office/ MS Excel removes it, as tries to show it as a number.

Comment: @Hiren Shah,
in text editor it is ok. but when i goes to open in CSV format 0 disappear.